# jar application closing within a few seconds after being opened with runtime exec (MacOS NetBeans)

Tags: java, macos, javafx, runtime, exec

I'm trying to open an external JavaFX application that I coded and built to play videos. So far, I've gotten it to open it, but it closes after a few seconds, and never actually appears.

Here is the code for when the user clicks the button to open the app:

```
try {
    String command = "java -jar /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/ContactEditor/dist1/mp4Player.jar";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have placed the dist folder of the actual program within the folder for the main app, but I have also tried running the original file within the original file-path (`mp4Player/dist/mp4Player.jar`).

Comment: Tried to add `p.waitFor()` at the end of the `try` block?

Comment: Implement *all* of the tips in [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html). That should give more info on the problem. Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: You are already in a JVM, my suggestion is to put the jar for your mp4Player and the JavaFX modules on the module path and launch the app from your existing Java code rather than spawning another process.  Does the command even work from the command line?  Recent JavaFX versions are designed to be run from the module path, not the classpath, so shaded jars aren't supported though it could work if you are lucky and have the right setup.

Comment: What happens when you run that command from a Terminal, with the same current directory as when you run it from within NetBeans?   Also use ProcessBuilder and redirect the stderr and stdout streams to the parent process to see if there are any messages that will help.